# Can't Filter on Assosciated Model cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have the following in my Usercontroller on my view function.

```
    $this->User->recursive = 2;
    $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id, 'Step.site_id' => $this->Auth->user('site_id')));
    $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));
```

Its filter perfectly the the User model but its simply ignoring the Step.site_id part and errors saying the field does not exist.

Any pointers where I am going wrong? I am using cakephp 2.*

I have already read a view questions about using contain but I wasn't able to get it working correctly.

Comment: How are user and step associated, what is the error message, and what are you expecting as a result?

Comment: A user has many steps and the error is that Step.site_id does not exist in the schema.

Comment: please do not paraphrase error messages (schema? just copy and paste the error message, and the query it came from into the question). That's to be expected - since there will be no join for that - what exactly is it you're trying to get 1) all users, and their steps if it matches the step_id 2) only users with a step record matching the site_id ?

Comment: This is the error I get. Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Step.site_id' in 'where clause'. I am expecting to get 1 user and all steps related to that user where the step.site_id = x. I hope that makes sense if not I can clarify further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess - "Step" is not the proper alias for the hasMany relationship (You should share more information.  This problem involves your model definitions and database table definitions)

Does this work?

```
$this->User->recursive = 2;
$options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id, $this->User->Step->alias . '.site_id' => $this->Auth->user('site_id')));
$this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));
```

Comment: `Does this work?` Since it's a hasMany: no. To get that to work a join is required.